# WPF datavalidator execution stops for unhandledexception but hitting continue makes everything work?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, c#-4.0, validation

In my code I have the following

```
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("You must enter a zip code!");
            }
```

and

```
<TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="ZipCode" Mode="TwoWay">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
```

When I execute and the code hits that exception, Visual Studio tells me that the Exception went unhandled by user code, but if I continue execution the desired WPF behavior (red outline around the textbox) occurs.  Does anyone have insight into this and, namely, how to test my validator without getting this annoying error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an unfortunate interaction between:

1. [first-chance exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), and
2. ["Just My Code"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx)

Maybe it's just me but "Just My Code" isn't that useful because I always want to see **all the code** in stack traces, etc.!  But it **is** nice for filtering and simplifying.

I believe that you'll have to turn off "Just My Code" in order to prevent "User-unhandled" exceptions like this because it's literally true that what Visual Studio considers "your code" isn't handling the exception.